# Replace root block in layout

Tags: layout, blocks

In attempting to avoid rewriting the `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Additional` block, I've been following my current strategy of removing the block with the old class and adding a new one with my new class:

```
<checkout_onepage_shippingmethod>
  <remove name="root" />
  <block type="my_checkout/onepage_shipping_method_additional" name="my.root" as="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml" />
</checkout_onepage_shippingmethod>
```

This works great for non-root blocks, but my alias technique doesn't seem to work in this case. Any ideas?

PS: I'm aware that this can be done with a rewrite.

Comment: Where are you putting this xml? Also, are you sure that you have the correct block type? Should it say `available` instead of `additional`?

Comment: You're correct. I had a typo when transcribing the snippet into this question (I changed some module names to protect the privacy of clients)

Answer (score 2):

I can't believe, this is working.

`<remove>` is the last statement processed before `toHtml`. This means, there is NO WAY to have a block with the name root when you remove it.

Bu you can just change the type of `root` by overriding the block, like in `<checkout_onepage_shippingmethod>` in `/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml:373`

```
<checkout_onepage_shippingmethod>
    <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method_available" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml"/>
</checkout_onepage_shippingmethod>
```

It is totally great, that you avoid rewrites!

Comment: Right. I no longer have a block *named* root, but instead a block with the *alias* root.

Comment: I don'T understand what you want to say with this.

Comment: When `getChild` is called, a block with a matching `name` or `as` will be returned. However, it appears that whatever loads the `root` block requires the `name`.

Comment: it depends on the context. in the child context you have to use the alias (I think alias is set exactly the same when no alias is defined). When you are in a global context, like with `<reference>` you have to use the name. But I still don't understand how this is connected with your problem.

Comment: It's connected in that I was hoping to be able to replaced the block named root with another block with the alias root. Unfortunately, the difference in context seems to make my attempted solution impossible.

Comment: ah, I don't think this works, because alias is inside of child context so no child, no alias. But I'm not sure about this. Why not replacing like in `checkout_onepage_shippingmethod` with just a new block?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11387/discussion-between-mpw-and-fabian-blechschmidt)

Comment: I'm sorry but I answer when I have time. When I should answer when you want it, you have to hire me :)